PowerApps DB connection issues
I created a PowerApps form and trying to fill dropdown and text boxes from "raw.Team"(to dropdown) and "raw.forecast" (to text boxes) views on one of the my Azure Serverless SQL database and allow users to modify numbers in the text box.
Once user click submit, PowerApps collects all dropdown and textbox data and store it into "forecast.csv" on Azure Storage container which "raw.forecast" view is built on top of it.
When I configure database connection with my individual user everything is working well but other users can't get data due to their users have no access to database.
To fix this issue, I created a service principal, grant read rights in on the database.
After these steps completed, I added database and related views to the PowerApps via "add data>Connections>Sql Server" via "Service Principal with Microsoft Entra ID apps" method. During the conenction creation process I can see that I connected to the database successfuly and get the list of views from db, also selected related ones and added as alias.
However, while I'm getting data from DB to the dropdown box with below code, I get "Error when trying to retrieve data from the network" error code.
Dropdown box query :
Distinct('raw.Team'; Department)
I tried to grant service principal writer rights, tried to get data from diffferent tables.

Due to poor formatting and length of your question, community members might pass it as TL;DR kind of situation. Please edit your question and ad some formatting to make it easy to read. Highlight your key points of your question, e.g. provide a screen shot of the error screen (if you are using an interface) and remember to hide your personal keys. Also, did you browse similar issue entries in Microsoft Fabric Community discussions? There are solutions regarding the same problem. You can try giving ownership, bc granting read rights sometimes won't work.
